# Ruby on rails: modeling foreign key relationships.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, foreign-key-relationship

In my app I have following models: `List`, `Item` and `Category`.

Each item `belong_to` a list.
Each item `belongs_to` a category.

Each list of items also needs to be somehow associated with multiple categories. Meaning that if user creates a category it will have a `list_id` assign to it that is equal to `id` of the list user was working on when the category was created. That way when user decides to get rid of the list I can also get rid of all of the custom categories that were created for that list. The problem is that I would also like to have some "default" categories: ones that are available for all of the lists. I am not sure how to model relationship between `lists` and `categories`. `belongs_to` is not working for me because "default" categories don't really belong to any specific list, they belong to all of the lists.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestion on how to handle that type of relationship!

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need `has_many` relation on the both sides of `Category` - `List` relationship.

You can keep category names that are the "defaults" in a constant inside the category model or the category can have boolean attribute so that you know whether to delete it or not.

To delete a category when a list is deleted you'll probably need to write a custom method that may run as an `after_destroy` callback on the List model.

Answer (score 0):

You want to set up a Many to Many relationship for your Category and List models.  To do that this is what you would do

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categorizations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :categories, :through => :categorize
end

class Categorization < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :list
end 

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categorizations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :lists, :through => :categorizations
end 

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :list
end
```

This will create a third table to keep track of the relationships between all the models.  Ryan Bates has a great [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/47-two-many-to-many) on this subject you should probably check out.

Then the `dependent: :destroy` will ensure that if one is deleted so is the relationship and then to ensure the other categories are deleted from that list you can use a before_destroy or after_destroy method.